# Read WordPerfect files with Python?

Tags: python, wordperfect

I really need to work with information contained in [WordPerfect 12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPerfect#Summary) files without using WordPerfect's sluggish visual interface, but I can't find any detailed documentation about the file format or any Python modules for reading/writing the files. I found a post on the web that seems to explain how to convert WordPerfect to text, but I didn't understand much about how it works.

http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2000-February/023093.html

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here's what I did. I read the file in binary mode, converted by the data into a string representation of the hex values, and used unofficial WordPerfect documentation to create regular expressions to swap out all the hex strings representing non-text formatting codes and meta data, then converted everything back into text.

A dirty piece of hacking, but it got the job done.

Comment: would you mind posting a sample of your working solution here?

Comment: [WP_Reader](https://github.com/gaudulli/WP_Reader) is a C# library that goes a step further and models the entire document according to the WP specification.  It's only half-way finished, but it is working for most of the "standard" formatting features in WP.  Six years later than the OP, but there is finally something that can be used to open up the obtuse structure of WordPerfect magic numbers it calls a document.

Answer (score 3):

The relevant part of your link is this:

```
os.system( "%s %s %s" % ( WPD_TO_TEXT_CMD, "/tmp/tmpfile", "/tmp/tmpfile.txt" ) )
```

Which is making a system call to an outside program called "wp2txt".  Googling for that program produces active hits.

Comment: Active hits are mostly for wikipedia dump files to text, I think you want: http://alter.org.ua/en/soft/win/convert/

Answer (score 2):

OpenOffice.org should read WordPerfect files, I think.

And you can [script OpenOffice with Python](http://udk.openoffice.org/python/scriptingframework/index.html).